# Running into SQL Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I tested with small batches using SQL Fiddle but when I input my entire data set into oracle it results in SQL Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression.

```
Select Staff.Number, Staff.Name, Staff.title, Staff.S_Location, 
count(Contact.Number) as X
from Staff
left join Contact
on Staff.Number = Contact.Number
group by Staff.Number
order by X desc;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add Staff.Name, Staff.Title and Staff.S_Location to the group by

Comment: Yes. In general, any item in the SELECT clause that isn't an aggregate function needs to be in the GROUP BY clause.